# Jest error when converting JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I'm in the process of converting a React project to TS.

I've converted one class and it builds and runs just like before but some jest tests started failing with this error-

```
Cannot find module '../../../components/keyboardInput/GeneralFieldInput' from 'DTCustomerInfoModalVehicleDescription.js'
```

I would appreciate any pointers on what's wrong

My setup:

jest.config

```
module.exports = {

  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmit": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true
    //"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  //"include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./cypress/**/*", "./coverage/**/*", "node_modules"]
}
```

webpack.config module

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: { loader: 'ts-loader' },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /style/,
        use: extractCSS.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },
    ],
  },
```

GeneralFieldInput.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import SmartInput from './SmartInput';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { inputFieldUtils } from '../../../lib/common/utils/inputFieldUtils';
import { REGEX_INPUT } from '../../constants/common';
import { disableAutoComplete } from '../../../lib/common/utils/utils';

type GeneralFieldInputProps = {
  name: string;
  promptKeyboard: boolean;
  type: string;
  title: string;
  value: string;
  hidePlaceholder: boolean;
};

const GeneralFieldInput = (props: GeneralFieldInputProps) => {

  return (
    <SmartInput
      name={props.name}
      promptKeyboard={props.promptKeyboard || false}
      type={props.type}
      title={props.title}
      value={props.value}
      hidePlaceholder={props.hidePlaceholder}
    />
  );
};

export default GeneralFieldInput;
```

how i'm importing the ts compoent

```
import GeneralFieldInput from '../components/keyboardInput/GeneralFieldInput';
```

package.json (tried to remove irrelivant things)

```
{
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --mode development --config webpack.dev.js --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8081",
    "start:hmr": "npm start -- --hot --fast",
    "start-pause": "npm run -s start --no-inline",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --optimize-minimize --progress --colors --profile  && chmod +x dist/start_nginx.sh",
    "prod-build": "rm -rf dist/ && npm run build && cd dist && http-server -P http://localhost:9081 -c0",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "jest --maxWorkers=4",
    "test-c": "jest --maxWorkers=6 --coverage",
    "test-all": "jest && cypress run --headed",
    "test-cypress": "npx cypress run",
    "build-css": "node-less-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "test-report": "nyc --reporter=html jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "lint:log": "eslint ./ -f json | node lintLogger --silent",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "cypress-headless": "cypress run",
    "prettier": "prettier --write '**/*.js'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-stage-1": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "nyc": "^11.7.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-migrate": "^0.1.21",
  },
}
```